# Free course on Spring Framework

Tags: spring

I am looking for a free online course on Spring Framework (similar to MongoDB university or coursera). However, I couldn't find anything for free. If anyone knows, please share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if these are similar to the ones you specified, but [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/)
can be a good bootstart for Spring FW.
Other than that, Spring - IMO - has a pretty [good documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) to start with the different "modules" of spring. I often start there, and if I have questions after reading it, the specific google searches usually give me the answers I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at Udemy.com and search for “Spring”.

1. [Introduction to Spring Boot](https://www.udemy.com/share/1007myA0MYcllURX4=/)
2. [Spring Framework and Dependency Injection for Beginners](https://www.udemy.com/share/1001RQA0MYcllURX4=/)

The above courses are free and unlimited.